# MYSQL - Selecting multiple rows in a single row

Tags: mysql

I have a table in `MYSQL` named as `permit_bills` which contains columns as `bill_no`, `alcohol_typ`, `origin`, `2000ml`, `1000ml`, `bill_date`. Table is shown below:

```
    +---------+--------------+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
    | bill_no | alcohol_typ  | origin  | 2000ml | 1000ml | bill_date |
    +---------+------------- + --------+--------+--------+-----------+
    |  2001   |    s         |   f     |   2    |    1   |01-02-2017 |
    |  2001   |    m         |   w     |   3    |    4   |01-02-2017 |
    +---------+--------------+---------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

I want to select all rows from above table into a single row based on their `bill_no` and `bill_date` and want to display the columns of `2000ml` and `1000ml` as per their `alcohol_typ` and `origin.

My output table must be like this:

```
    +---------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+-----------+
    | bill_no | s_f_2000ml   | s_f_1000ml  | m_w_2000ml | m_w_1000ml | bill_date |
    +---------+------------- + ------------+------------+------------+-----------+
    |  2001   |      2       |     1       |     3      |     4      |01-02-2017 |
    +---------+--------------+-------------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: You need PIVOT...take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: If it was me, I'd handle this kind of thing in application code - much more scalable and flexible.

Comment: I.e. do a GROUP BY, use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: http://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (pivot) query -

```
SELECT
  bill_no,
  MAX(IF(alcohol_typ = 's' AND origin = 'f', `2000ml`, NULL)) AS s_f_2000ml,
  MAX(IF(alcohol_typ = 's' AND origin = 'f', `1000ml`, NULL)) AS s_f_1000ml,
  MAX(IF(alcohol_typ = 'm' AND origin = 'w', `2000ml`, NULL)) AS m_w_2000ml,
  MAX(IF(alcohol_typ = 'm' AND origin = 'w', `1000ml`, NULL)) AS m_w_1000ml,
  bill_date
FROM permit_bills
  GROUP BY bill_no, bill_date
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your output table *needs* to look like that?

You may be able to use the GROUP_CONCAT function instead which is sometimes an amazingly useful tool. You will need to split or explode the values in your application, but it might be all you need.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat